# How manage and Add Cron Job from a Php Script?

Tags: php, cron

I want to make a Auto Scheduled Php Script .

actually my script update hash keys of 20 systems .. means it have to send 20 urls with some data . I need it to happen it every minutes but i want to manage it via php script not manually setup cron job . Also i want it to easy to pause and resume the cron at anytime ...

is there any solution ! Please help me ! thanks

- More Info :

I use Shared Platform of Hostgator also i will soon migrate it to dedicated once ! so please provide me solution accourding to it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the crontab directly from PHP may not be an option on a shared host.

An alternative approach is to have cron run a PHP script that acts as a daemon. So that PHP script runs other PHP scripts or performs actions as needed.

Comment: ...do not forget to set the appropriate script timeout. There is a difference when ran as CLI and when executed directly from other PHP script.